# How to give opacity to background-image

Tags: css

This is my css code for setting background

```
.faq{
    background-image: url('faq_bg.jpg');
}
```

How do I change opacity of this background-image without changing opacity of background-color

Comment: did you tried opacity:.5; something like this?

Comment: @K.B.M Yes.. i tried that.. the opacity gets applied to the whole page

Comment: can you provide whole code / a demo?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pseudo element to fake the background opacity, as there is not such property.

```
.faq::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('faq_bg.jpg');
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cant do it. there isn't yet a way to alter a images opacity. An option would be to use an element with your background colour, and another element positioned on top (or a pseudo element) with your image (and opacity)

i.e.

```
parent{
  background-color:#something;
  position:relative;
}

child{
  positon:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-image:url([etc])
  opacity:0.4;
}
```